# How to prevent eww from truncating lines?

Tags: eww, line-break

On a Mac, I would like to use "text to speech" to read web content.

I am using the eww browser.

"Text to speech" treats line breaks as the end of the sentence so I would like eww to display long lines, wrapped if needed, but not truncated.

I have tried (among many other things) this in .emacs:

```
(add-hook 'eww-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set-fill-column 99999)
            (auto-fill-mode 1)))
```

but eww still breaks the lines at the width of the buffer. Can you please advise me how to avoid these breaks?

Comment: Can "text to speech" not be configured to recognise multi-line paragraphs? I'm not familiar with it, but it just seems weird to me if that's not a supported format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little investigation indicates that you'll need to modify the various `shr-fill-*` functions to achieve this. The `shr-width` variable may or may not still be relevant at that point, but it seems reasonable to set that as well.

It you just want to hard-code this, you can redefine the functions like so:

```el
(eval-after-load 'shr
  '(progn (setq shr-width -1)
          (defun shr-fill-text (text) text)
          (defun shr-fill-lines (start end) nil)
          (defun shr-fill-line () nil)))
```

If you want behaviour you can toggle, I would probably advise the functions to *conditionally* do nothing, based upon some variable. e.g.:

```el
(defadvice shr-fill-text (around shr-no-fill-text activate)
  "Do not fill text when `shr-no-fill-mode' is enabled."
  (if (bound-and-true-p shr-no-fill-mode)
      (ad-get-arg 0)
    ad-do-it))

(defadvice shr-fill-lines (around shr-no-fill-lines activate)
  "Do not fill text when `shr-no-fill-mode' is enabled."
  (unless (bound-and-true-p shr-no-fill-mode)
    ad-do-it))

(defadvice shr-fill-line (around shr-no-fill-line activate)
  "Do not fill text when `shr-no-fill-mode' is enabled."
  (unless (bound-and-true-p shr-no-fill-mode)
    ad-do-it))

(define-minor-mode shr-no-fill-mode
  "Global minor mode which prevents `shr' and `eww' from filling text output."
  ;; :lighter (:eval (if (derived-mode-p 'eww-mode) " ShrNoFill"))
  :global t)

(shr-no-fill-mode 1) ;; To enable by default.
                     ;; M-x shr-no-fill-mode to toggle.
```

Comment: Answer updated with something you can toggle. I would have made it a buffer-local minor mode to be enabled with `eww-mode`, but shr renders to a temporary buffer in `fundamental-mode`, which makes things a little more awkward, so I've simply used a global mode.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using eww, and needed line wrapping. First I tried line truncation, but that cut through the middle of words.

[`visual-line-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Visual-Line-Mode.html) seems to provide intelligent line-wrapping on whitespace in the most straightforward way, and I'd be interested to know if that doesn't work for your reader.